# Excel pivot table not showing value of cell in right format

Tags: excel, time, format, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in excel of times, when I hover above the cell it shows the desired value (10:40:10, see screenshot), but the cell itself shows 0,4445 etc. The formatting is already set to time, how can I get the pivot table to display the hours?

Thanks a lot!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6kyK.jpg)

Comment: Did you set the field number property to time?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, should also be visible in the screenshot

Comment: Did you intend to sum the time field btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be formatted to default which is double. If you opened the VBE with Alt + F11 and then the immediate window with Ctrl + G and put the following:

```
?cdbl(timevalue("10:40:10"))
```

Result:

```
0.444560185185185
```

**Format your field as follows:**

When adding the field you can set number property to time ==>

Right click on required field > Number Format:

[image: right click format as Time]

Select Time:

[image: Time]

Output:

[image: Output]

Edit:

As per OP - Check you don't have "show formulas" in formula bar.

Comment: try the right click on time field in the pivottable just to confirm is formatted as time there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but I followed the steps and it is set to time already. On Friday it was still displaying a sum of the hours from the original data, but when I opened it today the format had changed and I can't change it back

Comment: Can you share the file if xlsx i.e. no macros? You could change data to dummy times and remove anything else if sensitive/remove personal info. https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: Ah I had "show formulas" selected in the formula tab, I didn't realise that it would impact the pivot table, very embarrassing! Thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.